# Can't add item in MutableList inside a LiveData Observer

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, mutablelist

I am trying to get multiple data from viwmodel via livedata ovserver with help of a for loop.

I am successfully get all data one by one and show them in Toast massage. But the problem is, I can't add those data inside a mutable list.

I can add item in this list from onCreate method. But I can't add any item from inside of observer.

Edited:

```java
private val vocabCount: MutableList<Long> = ArrayList()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     for (i in 1..5){
         folderListViewModel.getVocabCount("$i").observe(this,{it ->
              vocabCount.add(it)
         })
     }
}
```

every time `getVocabCount("$i")` function take a string peramiter and return a long value. Which I want to add in my Mutable list.

Comment: We need to see more code to understand what's happening and what you expect. Is that `for` loop inside `onCreate()`? Can you show us the contents of the `getVocabCount` function from your ViewModel?

Comment: I edited my question. ```for``` loop is inside my ```onCreate()``` method. and ```getVocabCount``` function take a string param and return a long value. return process is successfully done. I get this value. but I can't add those in my mutableList.

Comment: Do you mean it returns a `LiveData<Long>`? You can’t observe a Long, only a LiveData.

Answer (score 1):

use mutableListOf() instead of ArrayList() like this

```
val vocabCount: MutableList<Long> = mutableListOf()
```

then instead of "add" use "="

```
vocabCount = it
```